# How to properly apply torque or angular impulse to body in PlayN?

Tags: playn, jbox2d

I've been trying to apply an angular impulse to a Body object in PlayN, but to no avail. Whichever value (radials) I enter, the angle of the body never changes. I have tried to set the torque as well with no results.

**Example code that doesn't work:**

```
BodyDef def = new BodyDef();
def.type = BodyType.DYNAMIC;
Body body = world.createBody(def);

float degToRad = (float) (180 / Math.PI);
float radials = (float) (50 / degToRad);

// None of the following options work.
body.applyAngularImpulse(radials);       // Immediate angular change.
body.applyTorque(radials);               // Angular change over time.
```

**How can I get a valid body object to change its angle without manually setting its angular velocity (e.g. with setAngularVelocity)?**

Thanks in advance!

I did notice that the torque and angular velocity are reset by calling the setWake method, which I never do manually, but it is invoked by the Island class:

```
public void setAwake(boolean flag) {
    ...
    m_angularVelocity = 0.0f;
    m_torque = 0.0f;
    ...
}
```

**Note:** Setting the angular velocity is not an option because I rely on the physics simulation. I've found an [article for Box2D angle rotation](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/rotate-to-angle), but it didn't change the outcome of the applyAngularImpulse method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've debugged some, and come to the conclusion the values that I've been using were way too low. When going through the applyAngularImpulse code I noticed a few things:

```
public void applyAngularImpulse(float impulse) {
    if (m_type != BodyType.DYNAMIC) {
        return;
    }

    if (isAwake() == false) {
        setAwake(true);
    }
    m_angularVelocity += m_invI * impulse;
}
```

**m_invI** is a really low value, something like **2.44882598E-4** so it makes sense if I use a too low value, that there is just no visible effect. If calculate the impulse from the question's example multiplied by the **m_invI** field:

```
m_invI                                 = 0.00044882598 = 2.449E-4
impulse          = 50 / 180 / PI       = 0.08841941282 = 8.842E-2
m_invI * impulse = 2.449E-4 * 8.842E-2 = 0.00002165237 = 2.165E-5 <--
```

That means just an angular velocity increment of **0.00002165237** per update cycle... Which is way too low to be noticeable it seems.

Also, while browsing the Box2D forums for similar situations, I found it there's a best practice to include the body's inertia into your angular impulse calculation. Like this:

```
body.applyAngularImpulse(speedValue * body.getInertia());
```

The inertia tends to be a high value (+4000) for me.

*Hope this can be some help to others that have trouble applying an angular impulse or torque.*

Answer (score 2):

In my case I forgot to call

```
body.setFixedRotation(false);
```

Even though I was setting mass, an inertia of 0 was reported and all torques and angular impulses were ignored.

Apparently it is fixed by default.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

In my case I accidentally put my points in CW order (leading to negative area and zero mass). This was my incorrect code:

```
// incorrect version
triangleVertices.push(new B2Vec2(width / 2, 0.0)); // top
triangleVertices.push(new B2Vec2(0.0, height));    // left
triangleVertices.push(new B2Vec2(width, heightM)); // right
```

That looks like CCW, right? Nope, not in my coordinate system (+Y is down).

```
// corrected version
triangleVertices.push(new B2Vec2(width / 2, 0.0)); // top
triangleVertices.push(new B2Vec2(width, heightM)); // right
triangleVertices.push(new B2Vec2(0.0, height));    // left
```